# Any ideas on automating deployment with the Google AppEngine Launcher?

Tags: google-app-engine

I am trying to automate the deploy process with the Google AppEngine Launcher, and the one thing getting in my way is the password enquiry; I am trying to set it up so that I don't have to enter my password after the first time.

1. One approach I am looking at is to somehow ensure the cookie does not expire; any ideas on how this may be accomplished?
2. Are there any resources that detail the format of the `.appcfg_cookies` file, including the encoding?
3. Another approach I am looking into is the use of the `--passin` argument. Are there any resources on this?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 4):

Google App Engine now supports [OAuth tokens](https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/python/tools/uploadinganapp#oauth) to handle automated deployment, which does not expose your Google account password.

Answer (score 2):

The --passin argument is what you want - use appcfg.py with that and the --email argument, and provide the password from a file and you're sorted.

This seems fairly straightforward - what sort of 'resources' are you looking for?

Comment: Thanks for the tip!

I was looking for pointers regarding the .appcfg_cookies file; specifically, the garbled text and how its formed.