# How to auto deploy on Google App Engine from Hudson (or any other CI)?

Tags: google-app-engine

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Any ideas on automating deployment with the Google AppEngine Launcher?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2377032/any-ideas-on-automating-deployment-with-the-google-appengine-launcher)

I tried to auto deploy a jav app on GAE from Hudson using the appcfg tool. However appcfg only reads the email/password from stdin (and caches that for 24 hours or so). Of course this won't work in automated build, is there any way to supply the password in a file or such?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use the `--email` and `--passin` flags, documented [here](http://code.google.com/appengine/docs/python/tools/uploadinganapp.html#Command_Line_Arguments).

Comment: Ah, missed the --passin; thx !